# What causes the delay in displaying the splash screen in my Flutter app before it transitions to a white screen?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

In the main.dart file of my Flutter application, there's a noticeable delay in the initial display behavior. Upon launching the app, users are greeted with a plain white screen that persists for a duration of approximately 2-3 seconds before transitioning to display the intended splash screen.

It's worth mentioning that this behavior occurs without any reliance on external packages or libraries typically utilized for managing or presenting splash screens within the application. This delay in rendering the splash screen may affect the user experience and warrants further investigation into potential optimizations or adjustments within the codebase to ensure smoother and more seamless loading transitions.

the main.dart code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:you_matter/home.dart';
import 'package:you_matter/login.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await GetStorage.init('contactBox');
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const SplashScreen(), // Display SplashScreen initially
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
    );
    _controller.forward();

    // Wait for a short duration and then navigate
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      _navigateToNextScreen();
    });
  }

  _navigateToNextScreen() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
        );
      } else {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Login()),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: RadialGradient(
            center: Alignment.center,
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(192, 192, 194, 1),
              Color.fromRGBO(145, 142, 188, 1),
              Color.fromRGBO(51, 47, 114, 1),
            ],
            radius:
                0.9, // adjust the radius to control the spread of the gradient
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ScaleTransition(
                scale: _animation,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/Images/logo.png', // Replace 'assets/logo.png' with the path to your app logo.
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ScaleTransition(
                scale: _animation,
                child: const Text(
                  'YOU MATTER',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ScaleTransition(
                scale: _animation,
                child: const Text(
                  'Stand Against Violence',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash Try Flutter native splash for Android and iOS. It may take time initially to start the application. Native splash is always visible so you can get rid of the white screen using it

Comment: It's because you have `Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {...})` in initState